# Integration Google Hangout for SMS sending application

Tags: php, sms, google-api, google-hangouts

Is it possible to integrate google hangout on a web appliction(PHP) for sending and receiving SMS ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

The [current Dev-API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api-dev/) (for telephones) supports `gapi.hangout.av.effects`, `gapi.hangout.billing`, and `gapi.hangout.telephone`.

Comment: You can't use the API for sending SMS, so what kind of sample code do you expect?